# How to wrap relationship children into array in Vapor?

Tags: swift, vapor

I have a parent-child relationship, and the children need to wrap into array how can I do it?

```
event.testPrices = release.testPrices

final class Event: Content {
    var id: String
    var inProgress: Bool?
    var name: String
    var purpose: String?
    var testPrices: [TestPrice]

    init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Release { 
    var testPrices: Children<Release, TestPrice> {
        return children(\.releaseId)
    }
}
```

The assignment gives the error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Children' to type '[TestPrice]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query to form the `Future` array and then `map` it. Assuming you are in some controller/route where `event` contains the appropriate `Event` and `release` contains the appropriate `Release`, try this:

```
{
    release, event in

    _ = release.testPrices.query(on:request).all().map { testP in
        // testP is now [TestPrice]
        event.testPrices = testP
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, do you have idea, how to make this modification part of the response also? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472699/vapor-route-return-before-all-modification-done

Comment: Just an FYI - throwing away a Fluent future like this will lead to memory leaks